# TinyMCE fixed_toolbar_container configuration

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I tried using fixed_toolbar_container configuration inside tinymce.init, but it left me with plain html textarea instead of rich text editor. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="tinymce\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            inline: true,
            fixed_toolbar_container: "#mytoolbar",

            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
    </script>
</head>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <div id="mytoolbar" style="width:800; height:80; border : 1px blue solid"></div></BR>
    <textarea id="content"></textarea>
</form>
</html>
```

I'm using latest, 4.0.1, version of TinyMCE.

Could someone please tell me how should I disintegrate TinyMCE toolbar (which is attached to the top of the textarea) into a separate DIV/iFrame?

I'll appreciate a working sample code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You use the selector `textarea` and also `inline: true` at the same time, which is conflicting.  Either remove the inline setting, or change the selector to some DIV classname or ID that you want editable.

Comment: I am having the same problem. What if you want to use the inline toolbar with a textarea?

The inline toolbar looks good and I have to have the content in a textarea for the form-postback. I could copy the content on submit but it just feels like an ugly hack...

Comment: You do not have to keep the content in a textarea for the form postback to work, you can use inline mode on DIV's with for example classname `.editable`. TinyMCE will send along the data with same ID as the `DIV` - or create an ID if the element doesn't have any.

Comment: How would you do that in .net webforms? I doubt that it will work with viewstate since it has to have the textarea-control on the page. Why does tinymce4 not just work with standard textarea-tags like tinymce3 did? I guess I will skip the inline-editor for now and hope that they fix this.

Comment: I have no idea how viewstates work, but you could copy the content from the DIV to a hidden field and back on submit and pageload events. Even better would probably be to just find the tinyMCE code that deals with `fixed_toolbar_container` and make the changes needed to support in on non-inline mode too.

Comment: My brain must have shorted there for a while, obvisouly the quick and simple fix - without changing tinyMCE code - all you would need to do is to insert the POST data back into your DIV when the form has been submitted since it already gets sent with the form.

Comment: I made en easier solution. I use the focus/blur events on tinymce and hide/show the toolbar myself. Works great and I don't have to use divs. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: That's for hiding and showing the toolbar, but your question was about getting it detached from the editor, into a separate DIV with `fixed_toolbar_container`.  Totally unrelated? Well, never mind - great to hear you got it working!

Comment: Yea, a bit unrelated maybe. Hope I was not too far offtopick :) But i wanted the behavior from the "inline:true" setting of nicely showing/hideing the toolbar when the editor is clicked. I thougt i could use inline on a textarea to get that behaviur but doing it manualy worked fine.