# TinyMCE Toolbar and Menus

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any way I could disintegrate TinyMCE toolbar and menubar from the editor (by default it's attached at the top of editor)?

I would like to achieve something similar to Google Document where Toolbar and Menubar is at the top, detached from the actual editor giving it a feel of MS Word and not like a Notepad.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Thes is an option to insert the toolbar inside a custom element, which you can position at will:

```
fixed_toolbar_container: ".adminToolbar",
```

Comment: Hello @Christoffer Bubach, thanks for the reply. I have another question posted [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353412/tinymce-fixed-toolbar-container-configuration] where I also have posted a sample code. Could you please let me know what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I'll take a look, but could you mark this answer as right if it helped you?